# SQL Server cascade on delete

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2016 and trying to implement cascade on delete. It does work, but not if I put the code in a single script. The code for dropping the constraints on `--subproject` person and `--activity` then adding the constraint again have to be in separate files.

So this is in one file

```
 ALTER TABLE dbo.SubProjectPerson 
     DROP CONSTRAINT SubProjectPerson_SubProject
```

and this is in another file

```
 ALTER TABLE dbo.SubProjectPerson
     ADD CONSTRAINT SubProjectPerson_SubProject
         FOREIGN KEY (SubProjectID)
         REFERENCES dbo.SubProject(SubProjectID) 
         ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

That is the only way it works

Here is the script that I have

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    --subproject person
    ALTER TABLE dbo.SubProjectPersonRole 
        DROP CONSTRAINT SubProjectPersonRole_SubProjectPerson

    ALTER TABLE dbo.SubProjectPersonRole
        ADD CONSTRAINT SubProjectPersonRole_SubProjectPerson
            FOREIGN KEY (SubProjectPersonID) 
            REFERENCES dbo.SubProjectPerson(SubProjectPersonID) 
            ON DELETE CASCADE;

    ALTER TABLE dbo.SubProjectPerson 
        DROP CONSTRAINT SubProjectPerson_SubProject

    ALTER TABLE dbo.SubProjectPerson
        ADD CONSTRAINT SubProjectPerson_SubProject
            FOREIGN KEY (SubProjectID)
            REFERENCES dbo.SubProject(SubProjectID) 
            ON DELETE CASCADE;

    --activity
    ALTER TABLE dbo.Activity 
        DROP CONSTRAINT Activity_SubProject

    ALTER TABLE dbo.Activity
        ADD CONSTRAINT Activity_SubProject
            FOREIGN KEY (SubProjectID) 
            REFERENCES dbo.SubProject(SubProjectID) 
            ON DELETE CASCADE;

    --subproject
    ALTER TABLE dbo.SubProjectDocument 
        DROP CONSTRAINT SubProjectDocument_SubProject

    ALTER TABLE dbo.SubProjectDocument
        ADD CONSTRAINT SubProjectDocument_SubProject
            FOREIGN KEY (SubProjectID) 
            REFERENCES dbo.SubProject(SubProjectID) 
            ON DELETE CASCADE;

    ALTER TABLE dbo.SubProjectNote 
        DROP CONSTRAINT SubProjectNote_SubProject

    ALTER TABLE dbo.SubProjectNote
        ADD CONSTRAINT SubProjectNote_SubProject
            FOREIGN KEY (SubProjectID) 
            REFERENCES dbo.SubProject(SubProjectID) 
            ON DELETE CASCADE;

    --communication thread
    ALTER TABLE dbo.CommunicationThread 
        DROP CONSTRAINT CommunicationThread_SubProjectID

    ALTER TABLE dbo.CommunicationThread
        ADD CONSTRAINT CommunicationThread_SubProjectID
            FOREIGN KEY (SubProjectID) 
            REFERENCES dbo.SubProject(SubProjectID) 
            ON DELETE CASCADE;

   COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

This long script is running fine with no errors but no changes are being picked up for those two tables unless I run them in separate files. What's wrong here?

Comment: don't you need semi-colons after all of your `alter` statements?

Comment: Nope, that doesn't change anything, I have to split this up into 3 scripts for it to work

Comment: try to add print statement and see which one is not getting executed eg:
print 1
ALTER TABLE SubProjectPersonRole 
DROP CONSTRAINT SubProjectPersonRole_SubProjectPerson
print 1

Comment: the only statement being run is the first  2 alter statements for `dbo.SubProjectPersonRole`

Comment: How do you run that single script? Which tool do you use? Don't you need at least a `GO` after the whole block?

Comment: sounds like constraints need to be committed before you can use this column into the next constraint

Comment: It turns out I can't run this because of a design decision.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Use `GO` for every statement.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.SubProjectDocument 
DROP CONSTRAINT SubProjectDocument_SubProject

GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.SubProjectDocument
ADD CONSTRAINT SubProjectDocument_SubProject
FOREIGN KEY (SubProjectID) 
REFERENCES dbo.SubProject(SubProjectID) 
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```